# jQuery get multiple select items value on select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get all multiselect items value and based on that I am going to create dropdown list with the selected items.

My HTML is as below

```
<div>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <label for="title">Title</label>
        <input type="text" name="title" value="" placeholder="Your title" />
        <label for="cars">Select Cars</label>
        <select name="cars" id="cars" multiple>
            <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
            <option value="saab">Saab</option>
            <option value="opel">Opel</option>
            <option value="audi">Audi</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

I am trying to use below jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#cars').change(function(){
        $(this).after('<p>' + $('#cars').val() + '</p>');
    })      
});
```

This is giving me selected items value but than it is giving me in rows of all occurrence. I don't know how to say it but please see below image.

[image]

But I want only final result all the time and not one by one occurrence. Hope I explain it properly. :)

---

I want to convert after() paragraph to Dropdown select with the selected item. So is it possible to use php explode for it or any other way in jquery itself?

**Final Output I am looking for is**

```
  <div>
      <form action="" method="post">
      <label for="title">
          Title</label>
      <input type="text" name="title" value="" placeholder="Your title" />
      <label for="cars">
          Select Cars</label>
      <select name="cars" id="cars" multiple>
          <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
          <option value="saab">Saab</option>
          <option value="opel">Opel</option>
          <option value="audi">Audi</option>
      </select>

      <select name="sortedcars" id="sortedcars">
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
      </select>

      <input id="create" type="button" value="CreateDropDown">
      </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: What exactly does your desired output looks like?

Comment: @SalmanA I have added code for final output please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably this may help you

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#cars').click(function () {
            var values = $("#cars").val();
            var select = $("<select/>");
            for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                select.append($("<option/>", { html: values[i] }));
            }
            $("#dropdownDiv").html("");
            $("#dropdownDiv").append(select);
        })
    });
</script>
<body>
    <div>
        <form action="" method="post">
        <label for="title">
            Title</label>
        <input type="text" name="title" value="" placeholder="Your title" />
        <label for="cars">
            Select Cars</label>
        <select name="cars" id="cars" multiple>
            <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
            <option value="saab">Saab</option>
            <option value="opel">Opel</option>
            <option value="audi">Audi</option>
        </select>
        <input id="create" type="button" value="CreateDropDown">
        <div id="dropdownDiv">
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This is cool but what I want to do is creating dropdown as soon as they start to select. Or that is also fine if dropdown is already there but no option until they select from multiple box and instead of create drop down button will submit the actual form

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are adding a new `p` element every time the value is changed. Instead you can add a permanent element to hold the selected values and then update it when a value is selected

```
<div>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <label for="title">Title</label>
        <input type="text" name="title" value="" placeholder="Your title" />
        <label for="cars">Select Cars</label>
        <select name="cars" id="cars" multiple>
            <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
            <option value="saab">Saab</option>
            <option value="opel">Opel</option>
            <option value="audi">Audi</option>
        </select>
        <p></p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</div>
```

then

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#cars').change(function () {
        $(this).next('p').text($('#cars').val());
    })
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/67b4X/)

Comment: Thank Arun.. Can you please see my edited question after H line for dropdown select

Comment: @JatinSoni you want to create another select element with the values selected in `#cars` dropdown?

Comment: Yes I want `dropdown select`, not multiple select. So idea behind this is the first multiselect is to adding and sorting items and than the dropdown will allow to assign car to individual item later.

Answer (score 0):

In `PHP` it is better to use `explode()` instead of doing extra work in `jquery` like,

```
<?php
    print_r(explode(',',$_REQUEST['cars']));/// will return array of selected cars
?>
```

In javascript you can do this like,

```
$(function () {
    $('#cars').on('change',function () {
        if($('#cloneDropdown').length){// check if a drop down already exists
           $('#cloneDropdown').remove();// if yes, then remove it first
        }
        var $sel = $('<select id="cloneDropdown"/>');// create new drop down
        var opts=[];
        $(this.value).each(function(i,j){
             opts.push("<option>"+j+"</option>");// add all selected options
        });
        $sel.html(opts.join());// now new dropdown is created
        $(this).after($sel);// add new select after cars
    })
});
```

Comment: No, you have to submit the form and if you want to change it immediately on browser, then you have to use `javascript`.

Comment: But I need things before submit the form.